# Why is a div v-for with a calculated property not render?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

To avoid using `v-if` with `v-for`, as the manual recommends, I use the following construction:

```
<template>
<div id="fastopinion">
  <div v-for="comment in adminComment"
      :key="comment.id"
      v-show="feed_isVisible">
         <div id="user">{{ comment.user }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
   data() {
     return {
     comments: null,
     feed_isVisible: false,
     adminComment: [], 
                   }
        },

computed: {
 adminComment: function () {
    return this.comments.filter(function (comment) {
      return (comment.user === 'admin')
    })
  }

},

mounted() 
{ 
let vm = this;
vm.getComments();
}, 

methods: {

getComments() {
       let vm = this
       axios.get('/api/comments')
             .then(function(response) {
              vm.comments = response.data.data  
               })
           },

     },
}
</script>
```

But for some reason, this div is not displayed . And in the console I get an error:

```
The computed property "adminComment" is already defined in data.
```

But if I don't specify `adminComment: []`, then I get an invalid page with an error in the console:

```
Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of null"
```

and

```
Cannot read property 'filter' of null
    at VueComponent.adminComment
```

Help me figure this out. It is more important, of course, not to correct errors, but to display the div

Comment: `getComments` populated the `comments` data with an async callback, and your computed value will be calculated before the `comment` data is populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `adminComment` from the data object and keep only that of computed property, and comment should be an empty array initially:

```
data(){
  return {
     comments: [],
     feed_isVisible: false,

                   }
        },

computed: {
 adminComment: function () {
    return this.comments.filter(function (comment) {
      return (comment.user === 'admin')
    })
  }

},
```

axios response should be like  :

```
  axios.get('/api/comments')
             .then(function(response) {
              vm.comments = response.data
               })
           },
```